# How do you have user integer input in C#?

Tags: c#

I'm new to C# and I'm trying to have user integer input. But I get this error:

> A local variable named Test' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to Test, which is already used in a parent or current' scope to denote something else

Here is my code

```
using System;
    class MainClass {
      public static void Main (string[] args) {
        int Test = Console.ReadLine();
        int Integer;
        if (int.TryParse(Test, out Integer))
        {
          int Test = Convert.ToInt32(); 
        }
        else
        {
        Console.WriteLine("::INVALID::")
        }
      }
    }
```

If some one could help that would be appreciated.

Comment: You declare two variables called test; how does the compiler know which to use?

Comment: Even if you rename your variables, you're going to get several other errors.  Console.ReadLine() doesn't return an int.  Convert.ToInt32() requires a parameter.  You're missing a semicolon after Console.WriteLine().   Maybe others.

Comment: `How Do you [get] User Integer input` Make them get a digital keyboard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

bThere are several problems in your code.

On the fourth line you have

```
int Test = Console.ReadLine();
```

`Console.ReadLine()` does not return an `int`, but a **`string`**.

```
string Test = Console.ReadLine();
```

The name `Test` is not very descriptive and also violates the convention, that local variables should start with lower-case letter. So we can further improve the line to:

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();
```

Since C# 3 we also have implicit typing in form of `var` - thanks to this the compiler is able to automatically replace `var` with the type of the value on the right-hand side of the expression. In this case a `string`. So you could write the line as the following.

```
var input = Console.ReadLine();
```

As @PMV mentioned however, leaving `string` there instead of var results in better readability, because the return type on the right hand side is not clear from the name of the method.

The next line again violates variable naming conventions, `int value` or `int number` would be preferable. `Integer` could also be mistaken as type name for many developers coming from different languages - like Java. Note that we cannot use `var` here, because there is not right-hand side (nothing is assigned to the variable) and hence compiler has no way to recognize the type.

By now the error message should be gone, because we have changed the name of the `Test` variable. The error you have received tells you that you have redeclared the variable with the same name in the inside scope (inside the first `if` statement branch). This is not allowed in C#, because the outside scope variables are visible from the inner blocks.

Inside the first `if` block you also are trying to convert to `int` but this is an invalid statement, as you give the method no input and also you already have the parsed number after using `TryParse`

```
using System;

class MainClass {
    public static void Main (string[] args) {
        string input = Console.ReadLine();
        int value;
        if ( int.TryParse( input, out value ) )
        {
            //the user input is now stored in the 'value' variable
            //and you can normally use it as a number
            Console.WriteLine( value + 4 );
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("::INVALID::")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: when i put Console.WriteLine(input + 4); and input 6 it returns 64

Comment: No no, you cannot use `input` as a number. C# is a statically typed language, which means that when `input` starts out as a `string` it will stay a `string` forever. We have however parsed the value as a number into the `value` variable, which you can use. You can write `Console.WriteLine( value + 4 )`.

Comment: I have updated my answer with this example

Comment: This is the best answer by far, but I would encourage you to not "prop up" terrible questions like this by answering them. Have an upvote for the great explanation regardless!

Comment: I'm sorry for asking a bad question  BradleyDotNet but I am new to C# and don't have much experience i've only been using it for like 5 days now and am used to programming in python. - BradleyDotNET

Comment: My one gripe about this - I wouldn't recommend `var input` to a new user, nor would I recommend using `var` for a simple type like string.  The keyword is great for generic classes and query expressions where the actual typename would look like your cat rolled across the `<>` keys, but for something simple, I think it's best to keep it as `string input` which informs the reader of the type and also helps reinforce the knowledge that `input` holds variables of one and only one type.

Comment: That is true. In this case the return type is not clear from the method name, and hence it would be better to leave the type there.

Comment: Since I am new to C# I was wondering if you could I've me some tips for an object oriented language i'm used to using python so C# is a pretty big change.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed syntax errors

```
void Main()
{
    var TestString = Console.ReadLine();
    int Integer;
    if (int.TryParse(TestString, out Integer))
    {
        int Test = Integer; // maybe you dont need this
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("::INVALID::");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have user input converted to integer in `integer` variable.

```
    if (int.TryParse(Test, out Integer))
    {
      //Do whatever you want to do with integer here
    }
```

Also, change type of your variable `Test` to string

```
string Test = Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: this will fail here ```int Test = Console.ReadLine();```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use another variable name instead of Test.

```
int Test = Console.ReadLine();
```

`int IntegerTest = Console.ReadLine();` instead

Answer (score 0):

You declared variable Test twice. Once at 4 line, second in 8.
You used function Convert.ToInt32(); without argumen, but TryParse (if it's posiible) change value of out int parameter - you didn't need use Convert.ToInt32... ;)
Integer is a type name. You should use another name for your variable.

> Console.ReadLine();

return string, not int...

```
 string Test = Console.ReadLine();
    int res;
    if (!int.TryParse(Test, out res))
    {
      Console.WriteLine("::INVALID::")
    }
```